# A Boolean algebra of functions

Tags: boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

Consider a complete Boolean algebra $([A \to B], \leq_{[A \to B]})$ whose carrier set is the class of functions from the set $A$ to the set $B = \{1, 0 \}$, where $1$ and $0$ represent truth and falsity, respectively, where $(A, \leq_A)$ is a complete Boolean algebra.

Let $g \in [A \to B]$ be a function from $A$ to $B$. Suppose I want to define the smallest function $f \in [A \to B]$, such that, for all $x$, if $g(x) = 1$, then $f(x) = 1$ and $\forall S(S \subseteq \{x \mid g(x) = 1  \} \rightarrow f(\sqcup_{A} S) = 1$, where $\sqcup_A$ is the supremum operator of $(A, \leq_A)$. Can I express "the smallest function..." by using the supremum $\sqcup_{[A \to B]}$, as

$$\sqcup_{[A \to B]} \Bigl\{f \in [A \to B] \mid \text{for all }x\text{, if }g(x) = 1\text{, then }f(x) = 1\text{ and }\forall S(S \subseteq \{x \mid g(x) = 1  \} \rightarrow f(\sqcup_{A} S) = 1)  \Bigr\} $$

Comment: The *supremum operator* is not always defined in a Boolean algebra. For instance, in the Boolean algebra of all finite or cofinite subsets of $\Bbb N$, what is the supremum of the set $\{ \{2n\} \mid n \in {\Bbb N}\}$?

Comment: I have edited it to change it to a complete Boolean algebra.